# Using regular expression match ascending order and descending order in given list

Tags: regex, tcl

Using regular expression match ascending order and descending order in a given list.

```
set a {35214}
```

Depending on the order of presence, I would like to get whether it is a ascending or descending.

`12345` → ascending order

`54321` → descending order

Comment: I want single line expression

Comment: Why regex? And is 35214 ascending or descending?

Comment: [Perhaps, something like this](https://ideone.com/YK3g1p)?

Comment: just wanted to know to sort these numbers in ascending/descending order using single line of regular expression. Is it possible?

Comment: Regular expressions are not meant to sort anything, the strings are just matched or not matched by a given pattern. You need to use string methods/functions to operate on matched/captured strings.

Comment: % set a [list 35214]
35214

Comment: Regular expressions match strings. They do not sort the characters in them. Use the _right_ tool. You can specify REs for matching a particular ascending/descending sequence, but that's not the same thing at all.

Comment: Can we do the sorting instead of using lsort.

Comment: @user2640584 [Sure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

Second try... (see bottom for the first attempt)

To sort a sequence of digits:

```
set a 35214
# ascending order:
join [lsort -integer [split $a {}]] {}
# -> 12345
# descending order:
join [lsort -integer -decreasing [split $a {}]] {}
# -> 54321
```

`{12345}` is not a list of digits, as you seem to think, but a string containing five digits. A list of those digits can be written as the literal `{1 2 3 4 5}` or `"1 2 3 4 5"` (the braces or quotes are there to tell the interpreter that we want this to be a single list value and not five values), or as the expression `list 1 2 3 4 5`.

To sort a list of digits or integer values in ascending order:

```
set a {3 5 2 1 4}
lsort -integer $a
# -> 1 2 3 4 5
```

If the values are packed in a string you need to split it:

```
set a 35214
lsort -integer [split $a {}]
# -> 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you want the result of the sorting to be a packed string:

```
set a 35214
join [lsort -integer [split $a {}]] {}
# -> 12345
```

To sort in descending order:

```
set a 35214
join [lsort -integer -decreasing [split $a {}]] {}
# -> 54321
```

Documentation: [join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [lsort](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm), [split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm)

---

I got +1 for the first attempt, so I don't want to drop it entirely, but OTOH it seemed to be nowhere near what the asker wanted. You can find that answer, slightly edited, [on my personal blog](http://pelewin.blogspot.se/2015/08/ordered-numeric-sequences.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter. But I pass like variable set a {35214}  for this i need return value as 12345 --> ascending order or 54321 -->descending order using regular expression .

Comment: @user2640584: second attempt, still no regular expressions because I can't really see the point of trying to fit them into this.